# This add-on could not be installed because it does not match the Add-on Firefox expected

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I get this error when I try to inline install my addon: *This add-on could not be installed because it does not match the Add-on Firefox expected*

I'm using this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Installing_Extensions_and_Themes_From_Web_Pages

My extension is verified on AMO. This addon is a pure **XML**. I don't have any XPI file. And I'm pointing to this XML file in my inline install. The hash is OK (it's the same one that I got from the Firefox Developers page)

Can somebody help?

Comment: You need to reach out to the developer and tell them to get it signed. Firefox started forcing devs to sign their work for security.